# Rails update a record that has duplicate ids in db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, duplicates

I have a db with records that might have other records with the same id (yep, it really do be like that).

I have a line of code using standard Rails update:

```
Member.update(record.id, values)
```

Currently that updates all records with that id (no good). Based on the documentation, you can only put an id (or an array of ids)
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

I need to be able to specify the id, as well as another id, to get the truely unique record. Something like:

```
Member.update({id: record.id, crew_id: record.crew_id}, values)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
Member.where(id: record.id, crew_id: record.crew_id).update_all(values)
```

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. The `where` gets only 1 record, but the `update` still affects all records with the same id.

Comment: where doesn't get 1 record, it gets all the matching records based on the conditions. It is the find method that fetches only 1 record.

Comment: I mean by adding selectors like `crew_id: record.crew_id`, the `where` statement gets only 1 record. But calling `update` on one record still updates all records with the same id in the db

Comment: The update method is called on each of the records fetched by the where clause. Can you please check again?

Comment: Yep, checked, it doesn't matter how many records are fetched. `update` is creating a `where id = 1234` clause in the SQL query, which will affect all records with that id.

Comment: From what I understood, from where method an array of ids are returned. Then update is called on each of the records individually. update_all on the other hand creates one single query.